# VeraPDF reports error in PDF metadata when copyrighturl is not set

Tags: pdf-a, pdfx

I am preparing my thesis for PDF/A validity. I managed to produce a PDF that leads only one error in veraPDF, as follows:
[image: veraPDF error]
The error is not regarding the document itself but XMP metadata.

I found out that the xmpRights statement is created always, regardless how the directives \copyright, \copyrighted in .xmpdata are set. As soon as no copyrighturl is provided, an empty xmpRights statement is generated by pdfx in the pdfa.xmpi, leading to the error veraPDF reports.
Is there a possibility of not generating the xmpRights statement?

### `document.tex` file

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\title{My thesis}
\author{I by myself}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

Content.

\end{document}
```

### `document.xmpdata` file:

```xml
\Title        {This is the Title}

\Author       {Adam Adam}
%\CopyrightURL{http://}
\Copyright    {Copyright \copyright\ 2019 Adam Adam}
    \Copyrighted {False} 
\Keywords     {stuff\sep
               things}

\Subject      {This is where you put the abstract.}
```

Comment: Show a small example document that can be used for tests.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87912/add-metadata-in-pdf-as-type-pdf-a **produces Valid A-1b** (but NOT the PDF/X-1a as hinted in keywords so remove that tag X-1a was separately tested and passed using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355071/pdfx-pdf-x-1a-standard-metadata-xmpdata-not-showing-in-pdf)

Comment: @KJO Thanks for your links, but they are not relevant for my problem. The latter is considering PDF/X and not PDF/A. The former is regarding missing PDF/A metadata. I actually have the metadata provided to the pdfx package (in the .xmpdata file, you can also tell by the pastebin I added).

Answer (score 1):

[Later Edit] validation for your designated PDFA-1B is below, however looking closer at your "fail" **that is a PDFA-3** failure (19005-3) which I cannot emulate using any setting alterations, so **need to know how** you are validating to compare.

**Interesting** that VeraPDF will declare adobes [supplement](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf) a "fail" unable to find any valid class.

I can not test with Vera Online. It no longer seems to work with Edge.
However using latest offline update I get (N.B have confirmed that other files tested may not pass)

Validation Profile: PDF/A-1B validation profile
PDF/A compliance:  Passed
Statistics 
Version: 1.12.1
Parser: GreenField
Build Date: 2018-05-08T22:06:00+01:00
Processing time: 00:00:01.675
Total rules in Profile: 103
Passed Checks: 1439
Failed Checks: 0

Also online
https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx and https://bfo.com/blog/2017/11/08/verify_pdfa_online/
The following shows as Compliance pdfa-1b / Validated PDF/A-1b:2005
The document does conform to the PDF/A-1b standard. Done.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
\Keywords{stuff\sep things \sep PDF/A-b}
\Title{This is the Title}
\Author{Adam Adams}
\Copyright{Copyright \copyright\ 2019 Adam Adam}
\Copyrighted {False}
\Subject {This is where you put an abstract.}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{My thesis}
\author{I by myself}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}
Content.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485260/verapdf-reports-error-in-pdf-metadata-when-copyrighturl-is-not-set
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using your source, I got the same error. I use the offline veraPDF greenfield version. So maybe it's just that my pdfx version is buggy and outdated? I currently have 1.5.6. Sadly, I was not successful in finding a proper change history online.

Comment: Check you are using latest greenfield production version 1.12 not developer 1.11 or 1.13 and let it auto test type it should only test then for 1B as in header not 3A etc It worked with tex live 2018 and MiKTeX equally well

Comment: Just to check I used PdfLaTeX which calls pdfTeX not plaintex or any other variant but you are correct that PDF/A support including XMP was improved in pdfx 1.5.84 (2017)